# image.backgroundColor change and repeat animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm trying to create an animation for my application. I start an animation with my button `startButton`. This button starts the animation of my `UIImage` and changes its background color.

I would like to repeat this animation but I can't find a method to do that.

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {
    NSString * chosenColor = _colorField.text;
    NSString *color = [chosenColor substringToIndex:6];
    NSLog(@"colore: %@", color);
    NSString *color1 = [chosenColor substringFromIndex:8];
    NSLog(@"colore2: %@", color1);
    NSScanner* pScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: color];
    NSScanner * pScanner2 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:color1];
    unsigned int rgbValue = 0;
    unsigned int rgbValue2 = 0;
    [pScanner scanHexInt: &rgbValue];
    [pScanner2 scanHexInt:&rgbValue2];

    int index = 8;
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [chosenColor characterAtIndex:index-2]];
    NSLog(@"tempo: %@", time);

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [time doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"interval: %f", timeInterval);

    _colorImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0
                                                  green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0
                                                   blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:timeInterval animations:^{
        _colorImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0
                                                      green:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0
                                                       blue:((float)(rgbValue2 & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    } completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you try recursive function which calls it self

Comment: i don't understand sorry

Comment: okey just tell me how many times you want to repeat the method

Comment: which is your code for animation..

Comment: i would like to repeat many times that i write in a textfield , i covert the count from string in a textfield     NSString *count = [chosenColor substringFromIndex:14];
int number = [count intValue];

Comment: _colorImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:timeInterval animations:^{
        _colorImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0
 green:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0
                                                       blue:((float)(rgbValue2 & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    } completion:NULL];

Comment: please check out my answer. Answer is relate to recursion animation code is same as what you have posted in question

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSTimer like this:

```
self.animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                       target:self
                                                     selector:@selector(doAnimation:)
                                                     userInfo:nil
                                                      repeats:YES];
```

Whenever you want the animation to end, just call [self.animationTimer invalidate]. The doAnimation: method will take the NSTimer object as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this method call it.

```
-(void)runAnimationWithRepeateCount:(int)count
{
_colorImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];

[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    _colorImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue2 & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue2 & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    count = count-1;
    if (count>0) {            
        [self runAnimationWithRepeateCount:count];
    }
}];
}
```

and pass the count like how many times you want to run the animation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but with this method i don' t start the animation with the button

Comment: you can call this method on button click IBAction method.

Comment: i don't now how can call this method in a IBAction ... i'm new in this world of developer

Comment: in count Xcode give me a error "Variable is not assignable (missing__block type specifier)

Answer (score -1):

Use `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` option to infinitely repeat UIView animation.

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                      delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay 
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options 
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations 
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Comment: where i put the repeat count ?

Comment: It only supports infinite count. Otherwise use CABasicAnimstion